# How to make this recursive code execute synchronously in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a recursive function that execute synchronously in javascript and gives me the result that i desired. But when i was executing the same code in node.js the result of the function is delivered even before the function got executed completely. can someone help me execute the code synchronously in node.js?

I have tried with callbacks also. But I could see finals got returned even before the inner recursive functions got executed.

Can someone help me get this code work synchronously in node js?

```
var finals = [];

function algo(parentApi)
{
    var i, j, k = 0;
    var parents = [];
    for (j = 0; j < parentApi.length; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < childProjectApiList.length; i++)
        {

            if (parentApi[j].api_tag == childProjectApiList[i].dependent_api)
            {
                parents[k++] = childProjectApiList[i];
            }
        }
        if (parents.length > 0)
        {
            async.map(parents, projectComponent.getApiResult,
                function(err, result)
                {
                    finals = finals.concat(result);
                    algo(parents);
                });

        }
    }
    if (j == parentApi.length)
    {
        return finals;
    }
}
```

i expect the function to return finals after whole recursive process is completed but it returns me empty array.

Comment: you can't have asynchronous code produce synchronous results - it's never possible because asynchrony can't be tamed

Comment: @JaromandaX is there a way to produce same result in asynchronous manner

Comment: yes, but it requires a huge rewrite, especially since there is recursion - does the order in `finals` matter? there's no predictable order in your code

Comment: @JaromandaX , the order in finals doesnot matter

Comment: still not easy, quite a big rewrite - but it will always remain asynchronous - so you'll also need to change how the function is used in your code

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var finals = [];
```

function algo(parentApi){
    var i, j, k = 0, parents = [];

```
for (j = 0; j < parentApi.length; j++) {
    for (i = 0; i < childProjectApiList.length; i++) {
        if (parentApi[j].api_tag == childProjectApiList[i].dependent_api){
            parents[k++] = childProjectApiList[i];
        }
    }

    if (parents.length > 0){
        async.map(parents, projectComponent.getApiResult, function(err, result) {
            finals = finals.concat(result);
            algo(parents);
        });
    }else if (j == parentApi.length) {
        return finals;
    }
}
```

}